# Check if a line intersects the base of a non planar polygon in a 3D world

Tags: algorithm, polygon

I have a non-planar **concave** polygon in a 3D world, (It is expanded up, but that doesn't matter for my question, so let's assume it is (kindof) 2D)

What I mean by non-planar polygon:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

I have a line that goes from OUTSIDE of the polygon, to another point that can be inside the polygon, or may not. **I want to test if that line intersects the base of the polygon** (I already know how to check if it intersects the lines of it). The point of this is testing if an object is inside the polygon.

By base, I mean the "bottom" (top as well, but that should be the same considering the polygon), could possibly be referred as the plane that all the points lie on? 
In #2 screenshot, the biggest 'part' of that screenshot is a base.

Speed is an important factor, accuracy isn't as much.

This is for detecting if an object is inside the polygon, I know how to check the lines/sides of polygon, but no idea as for base. If there is another (possibly better) way of doing it, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: What do yo mean by base?

Comment: @user2136963 By base, I mean the "bottom" (top as well, but that should be the same considering the polygon), could possibly be referred as the plane that all the points lie on? In #2 screenshot, the biggest 'part' of that screenshot is a base.

Comment: If accuracy isn't important. maybe calculate an axis aligned bounding box, and see if the ray intersects that.

Comment: @NullSet do you mean something like this? https://i.imgur.com/ArQcwZR.png If so, that would be way too inaccurate. With inaccuracy I'm talking about minimals.

Comment: Is your polygon convex?

Comment: @NullSet Apology, didn't realise there were 2 different types. It's concave.

Comment: Can you approximate your polygon with 2 or 4 triangles?

Comment: @samgak Not exactly, the polygon(s) will vary a lot.

Comment: I don't mean use the same triangles each time. I mean (for example) finding the midpoint and then drawing an X across the surface through the midpoint to split it into 4 triangles. Also, there's no such thing as a non planar polygon, by definition. Is it some kind of parametric surface?

Comment: @samgak I see what you mean, and I think could go with splitting into 4 triangles, but not sure if it would really help. By non planar polygon, what I mean is a 2D polygon, put into 3D world and the height of the points are lowered/heightened(changed). Here's an example of what I mean (horrible art skills) https://i.imgur.com/KQKwVGb.png the red is the polygon, the black is just to help visualise the height differences.

Comment: @Guest But there is no single plane on which all points lie. Can you just create a new polygon from original, where all heights are set to zero and test intersection with that polygon? Or do you need to check for intersection with a subpolygon containing the most number of points? Or with a subpolygon containing  the most number of  *adjacent* points? Or something else?

Comment: In these cases you can iterate over smallest possible planar elements (squares in screenshot 1), extract plane equation from each, normalize it and increment score for each equation. Then, return points which belong to plane described by equation with the best result.

Comment: @user2136963 I need to test if an object is inside the polygon. By having all points on same plane, it's a no problem for testing intersections. Here's an example https://i.imgur.com/8ASxkRH.png where the red arrow is the ray I'm drawing. In this case, unless I can detect if it goes through the base, it won't return if the player is in the polygon. I don't completely understand your second post. Is it something like this?(2D representation) https://i.imgur.com/9vgWXrh.png perhaps you could give a simple example, if you don't mind.

Comment: I wrote how to detect the gray part on screenshot 1. But if you consider all quads a "base", it's not really useful

Comment: Can you use a GPU? The plane can be represented by a heightmap. The line - as a very long segment, color of which varies with z axis, If you have two pixels of the same color and position, you have intersection. Should be quite fast

Comment: @user2136963 the first screenshot is just to show what I mean by non planar. Not exactly what my polys will be like. I can't use a GPU, it's all calculated on a dedicated server, with no gpu availability.